# asp.net core 3.1 app running in-process ignoring appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Debugging my .net core 3.1 app recently upgraded from an earlier core version, I noticed that it works when running out-of-process, but trying to run it with IIS in-process, it crashes. Stepping through the code, the variables I defined in appsettings.json appear to be null when in-process mode. This leads me to believe I need to migrate these values back to the web.config for running in-process, but I can't find any reference to this.

Am I chasing the wrong thing here or is there some other deployment step I'm missing etc?

Comment: Have you added it in your configuration builder?

Comment: if I switch this to outofprocess, it runs fine- so I think the configuration is all set up, just something not clicking when changing to in-process?